# Split string by character per character occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, split

*SSMS 2016 Enterprise*

If I have a column with the following string:

```
$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/
```

How can I create the following result

```
Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 

   $      Harmony   Maintenance   6.0         Dev
```

the maximum number of  `/` in a string will be 27. So in each row the number of `/` can vary as well as the string between them.

I need to create 27 column and populate them, if the string only has 5, then the following tables would be null.

I tried solutions using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`, but I am not being able to make it work as I want so far.

Thank you guys!

Comment: just one of the many other present in SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: Can you show MSSQL version?

Comment: It is running on SQL Server 2016 etsa

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

Comment: I believe 2016 has the new String_Split Function.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requiers some coding, but the general idea of mine is:

create dynamicly query, then execute it.

I provided solution, which you can apply. I based it on fixed string (that you provided),, assigned it to `@str` variable and modified it. But you can put it all in a loop, on every run of the loop you can assign it new string, which will be transformed in a given way. After each loop execution, the insert query will be run.

```
create table #resultTable(
col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50), col3 varchar(50), col4 varchar(50), col5 varchar(50), col6 varchar(50), col7 varchar(50),
col8 varchar(50), col9 varchar(50), col10 varchar(50), col11 varchar(50), col12 varchar(50), col13 varchar(50), col14 varchar(50),
col15 varchar(50), col16 varchar(50), col17 varchar(50), col18 varchar(50), col19 varchar(50), col20 varchar(50), col21 varchar(50),
col22 varchar(50), col23 varchar(50), col24 varchar(50), col25 varchar(50), col26 varchar(50), col27 varchar(50)
)

declare @tableToSplit table(id int identity(1,1), ColumnWithStringToSplit  varchar(2000))
insert into @tableToSplit values ('$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/'),
('$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/123/'),('$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/123/456/')
select * from @tableToSplit

declare @howManyRows int, @id int, @iterator int = 1
select @howManyRows = count(*) from @tableToSplit

declare @i int, @counter int, @values varchar(1000), @query nvarchar(2000)

while @iterator <= @howManyRows
begin
    set @query = 'insert into #resultTable ('
    --get values from table
    select top 1 @id = id, @values = ColumnWithStringToSplit from 
    @tableToSplit
    --count how many strings we will have, which is equal to number of '/' in string
    set @i = len(@values) - len(replace(@values,'/',''))
    --get rid of last forward-slash
    set @values = left(@values, len(@values) - 1)
    --replace all slashes, so it can be used as part of insert statement
    set @values = '(''' + REPLACE(@values, '/', ''',''') + ''')'

    set @counter = 1
    while @counter <= @i
    begin
        set @query = @query + 'col' + cast(@counter as varchar(2)) + ','

        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
    --get rid of last comma and append rest of the query
    set @query = left(@query, len(@query) - 1) + ') values ' + @values

    exec sp_executesql @query
    --we processed that row, so we need to delete it
    delete from @tableToSplit where id = @id
    set @iterator = @iterator + 1
end

select * from #resultTable
```

Here's picture of a result (there's 27th column, if you wonder):
[image]

Comment: I just dont know how to adapt this to the case on which I have a table with

ID | ColumnWithStringToSplit

Comment: Hey Michal! 
I have three solutions, one is one of them, thank you a lot!
I am going to test the best performance of all the three and check which one provides me the fastest solution. Anyway this was amazing, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function first to split your string, and then pivot it afterwards.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dba_parseString_udf] (
      @stringToParse VARCHAR(8000)  
    , @delimiter     CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @parsedString TABLE (stringValue VARCHAR(128)) AS
BEGIN

/* Declare variables */
DECLARE @trimmedString  VARCHAR(8000);

/* We need to trim our string input in case the user entered extra spaces */
SET @trimmedString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@stringToParse));

/* Let's create a recursive CTE to break down our string for us */
WITH parseCTE (StartPos, EndPos)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS StartPos
        , CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter) AS EndPos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EndPos + 1 AS StartPos
        , CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter , EndPos + 1) AS EndPos
    FROM parseCTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @trimmedString + @delimiter, EndPos + 1) <> 0
)

/* Let's take the results and stick it in a table */  
INSERT INTO @parsedString
SELECT SUBSTRING(@trimmedString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)
FROM parseCTE
WHERE LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@trimmedString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)))) > 0
OPTION (MaxRecursion 8000);

RETURN;   
END
```

After this i would pivot your results:

```
----For test purpose-----
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
ID int null,
string nvarchar(500) null
)

INSERT into @Table (ID,String)
VALUES(1,'$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/'),
(2,'$/Harmony/Maintenance/6.0/Dev/Test/')
--------------------------



 select [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5],[Column6],
[Column7],[Column8],[Column9],[Column10],[Column11],[Column12],[Column13]
,[Column14],[Column15],[Column16],[Column17],[Column18],[Column19],
[Column20],[Column21],[Column22],[Column23],[Column24],[Column25],
[Column26],[Column27]
 FROM 
(
 SELECT 'Column' + cast(Row_number() over(Partition BY ID order by ID) as 
varchar(50)) as ColumnRow,
* FROM @Table
CROSS APPLY dbo.[dba_parseString_udf](string,'/')
) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT
(
min(stringValue)
FOR ColumnRow IN ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[Column5],
[Column6],[Column7],[Column8],[Column9],[Column10],[Column11],[Column12],
[Column13]
,[Column14],[Column15],[Column16],[Column17],[Column18],[Column19],
[Column20],[Column21],[Column22],[Column23],[Column24],[Column25],
[Column26],[Column27])
)
AS
PivotTable
```

Comment: This is looking amazing!
But how can I use this function to reference to a column and make what it does when I input the string manually inside of the function?

Comment: Im gonna make some changes to the script. Hang on :)

Comment: Take a look at my script again, i edited it  a bit. I hope you have some sort of ID on your column, because i use that to order the columns.

Comment: Sorry had an order by in my partition by using stringvalue, its deleted now else it would sort wrong :)

Comment: Hey PlaidDK! I have three solutions, one is one of them, thank you a lot! I am going to test the best performance of all the three and check which one provides me the fastest solution. Anyway this was amazing, thanks a lot man!

Comment: I getting some errors when I try to create a view that provides the PivotTable results along with the respective ID

Comment: @LuisDoCantoBrum Can you tell me what error ? Maybe some code?

Comment: In the end I managed to do it, but it runs very slow has my dataset is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option using a little XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY.

Easy to expand to 27... the pattern is pretty simple

> **EDIT - Added 2ndToLast - Also added NullIf() which is optional**

**Example**

```
Select B.*
      ,[2ndToLast] = reverse(Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(reverse(A.SomeCol),'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)'))
 From   @YourTable A
 Cross  Apply (
                Select Pos1 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos2 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos3 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos4 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos5 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos6 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos7 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos8 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)'),'')
                      ,Pos9 = nullif(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)'),'')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: The only problem with XML path is that it uses your CPU to max, and if there is many rows, you would have problems.

Comment: Pretty neat this one. Simple and does the work, just need to check on the performance, but this is awesome

Comment: @LuisDoCantoBrum Curious to know how it performs on your real-world data

Comment: @JohnCappelletti will test it in like 5 minutes, will let you know!

Comment: By the way John, is it possible to have like a:
2ndLastNonNullPos,  which would be a column that would give the string of the 2nd last non null (so, not the last position, but the previous to the last)

Comment: @LuisDoCantoBrum I've read your last comment several times.  I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: @JohnCappelletti he wants the 2nd last position - in this example he wants pos4 in the column 2NdLastNonNullPos

Comment: @LuisDoCantoBrum See update/edit.  Gets a little uglier.  I see now that you are on 2016.  Perhaps string_split() in concert with pivot would be safer.  This assumes the string ends with a "/"

Comment: Thanks John! This is a good solution for smaller datasets than my own unfortunately, loved the simplicity though